# How to set document id when using elasticsearch nodejs API

Tags: elasticsearch

My requirements are simple, I need to index a document in ES with a given ID, in the dev tools I can do so by passing the id in path parameters `PUT my-index-000001/_doc/1?` when I try to do the same using nodejs [API](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js) by passing `_id` ... I get the error `mapper_parsing_exception: [mapper_parsing_exception] Reason: Field [_id] is a metadata field and cannot be added inside a document. Use the index API request parameters.` the same applies if I try in dev tools too, so how can I set a document `_id` noting am doing so in order to set a `parent:child` relationship within the same index like explained [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html#_parent_join_and_performance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Field [_id] is a metadata field and cannot be added inside a document.

If you see above error message, it is clearly indicated that you cannot pass `_id` into your document body.

You need to provide `id` outside document body as shown below (this is just example code as you have not provided sample code not sure how you are indexing document):

```js
 client.index({
     index: 'blog',
     id: '1',
     type: 'posts',
     body: {
         "PostName": "Integrating Elasticsearch Into Your Node.js Application",
         "PostType": "Tutorial",
         "PostBody": "This is the text of our tutorial about using Elasticsearch in your Node.js application.",
     }
 }, function(err, resp, status) {
     console.log(resp);
 });
```